# How to print an ant design table with repeated header on each page

Tags: reactjs, printing, antd, page-break

I'm using ant design table in a react app and struggle to print a large table (large than one page to print) with repeated table headers on each page.
As it is, ant renders two html table dom nodes for one table component. One for the header, one for the body. Thus, the browser has no clue what to repeat upon page break as the 2nd table (with the content) has no html thead .
Manipulating the dom by merging the thead and tbody of the two rendered tables seems to work but feels a bit cumbersome/awkward.
Anybody with a best practise or 'the right way to do it' approach?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey bot,
this will not provide any additional info as neither codepen, fiddle or any other sandbox provides a decent print preview to reproduce this issue.